# Derivative of $F(x)=\int_0^\sqrt{x} e^{-t^2} \;dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> **True/False**: The derivative of $$F(x)=\int_0^\sqrt{x} e^{-t^2} \;dt$$  at $x=1$ is $e^{-1}$

I came across the following result in Spivak calculus:

If $h$  is continuous and $f,g$ is differentiable, then the derivative of $$F(x)=\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) \;dt $$ is $$F'(x)=h(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)-h(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) $$

---

Here $\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable at $1$, and $e^{-t^2}$ is continuous,   so by above result, $$F'(1)=e^{-x} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}\;\Big|_{x=1}=0.5e^{-1}$$

So the statement is false. Is this correct ?

Also  $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but we have dealing with $x=1$. So the mentioned result applicable to $x=1$ . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x) = \int_0^x e^{- t^2} dt $, so $g'(x) = e^{- x^2}$.

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, so $f'(x) = { 1\over 2 \sqrt{x}}$.

$F = g \circ f$ and so 
$F'(x) = g'(f(x)) f'(x) = e^{-x}{ 1\over 2 \sqrt{x}}$
and $F'(1) = {1 \over 2e} $.